# jdbc is not working in spring security

Tags: spring-security, spring-jdbc

I am developing a simple struts2 login using spring security 
and everything working properly.But when i use jdbc to load users and their corresponding roles,it always showing my custom invalid user page.There is no error showing and i dont know what is wrong.

My applicationcontext-security.xml

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin.action" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/WEB-INF/Content/403.jsp" />

    <form-login login-page="/WEB-INF/Content/login.jsp"
                default-target-url="/admin.action"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.action?error=true"
    />
    <logout logout-url="/login.action?logout=1" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query="select username,password from users where username=?"

                           authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.username = ur.username and u.username=?"
        />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

my dataAccessContext.xml is

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Boban"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="veradis"/>
</bean>
```

When i directly give user,password and authority it works.I searched a lot in google and found similar errors,but nothing works.I Checked the sql query and it works perfectly.I am stuck with this program.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the query for login missing one field **enabled**

Try something like this:

```
"select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
```